# How to keep the title attribute value visable after clicking?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Consider the following HTML markup:

```
<img src="info.png" title="Password should contain 6-10 characters">
```

In the output, when users hover on the image, the value of the title attribute is displayed in a pop up. This is a nice idea to display information to the users.

But, this information is vanished when users click the image (please note users may tend to click rather than hovering)

What can I do (using jQuery for example) to keep the information visible (even if the user clicks) as far as the mouse pointer is on the image?

I tried the following, but this did not solve this issue:

```
jQuery('img[src="info.png"]').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
        });
```

**EDIT :**
Are there any way to do "*clicking is equal to hovering*" in jQuery?

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to create your own tooltip.

```
<img src="info.png" alt="">
<span>Password should contain 6-10 characters</span>
```

You don't need JavaScript, pure CSS is enough:

```
img[src=info.png] + span {
    display: none;
}
img[src=info.png]:hover + span {
    display: inline;
}
```

**Edit:** If you don't want to touch your HTML, you can create the tooltips with script.  Here's a jQuery example:

```
var img = $("img[src=info.png]");
$("<span>").text(img.attr("title")).insertAfter(img);
img.attr("title", "");
```

Comment: Sounds good, but is it possible to alter this idea without changing HTML markup?

Comment: You can do it with script.  I'll update my answer with an example.

Comment: The problem here is to position and style the contents of <span/>.

Comment: I don't understand.  Are you asking how to style the span?  Use the CSS I provided above and add style attributes as needed.  Can you be more specific?

Answer (score 1):

The display of `img`'s `title`s or `a`'s `link`s is dependant on the browser and you have no control over it. If you want to have your own behaviour and make sure this behaviour is cross-browser, you will need to :

1. get rid of default browser behaviour by removing all `title` and
   `alt` attributes
2. reimplement your own tooltips using one of many
   libraries available

Good luck